# how do i write a single query to insert the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

iam trying insert rows into a sql table in java. i need to insert into a  table simulateneously with 2 different data.here am using 2 queries to insert data to dbo.Company obtained from some manipulations into a single table

```
    statement1.executeUpdate("insert into   
    dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
    values('"+cname[i]+"','"+ts+"','"+ts+"')");

    statement3.executeUpdate("insert into 
    dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
    values('"+EMpname[i]+"' ,'"+ts+"','"+ts+"')");
```

i need to insert cname[i] and EMpname[i] into dbo.Company using single query... please help to write this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `VALUES` supported since 2008. If your server version is lower use `UNION`: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/

Comment: There's an updated version of the blog post [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/).

Answer (score 1):

Use insert statement in form:

```
INSERT Table(fields)
VALUES 
  (set1), 
  (set2),
  ...,
  (setN)
```

Your case is:

```
statement1.executeUpdate("insert into   
dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
values('"+cname[i]+"','"+ts+"','"+ts+"'),
('"+EMpname[i]+"' ,'"+ts+"','"+ts+"')");
```

Comment: this is giving me the following error   Exception in connecting to DB[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: :-it is showing. type annotations are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable type annotations)

<identifier> expected

Comment: Which language you use, I wrote it for c#

Comment: @user1063145 Which version of SQL Server are you using. The above syntax was added in SQL Server 2008. MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "insert into   
dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
values('"+cname[i]+"','"+ts+"','"+ts+"');" + "insert into 
dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
values('"+EMpname[i]+"' ,'"+ts+"','"+ts+"')";

statement1.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: got this error:-Connection is busy with results for another hstmt Rows are inserted into SQL Database

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a transaction.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
statement1.executeUpdate("insert into   
dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
values('"+cname[i]+"','"+ts+"','"+ts+"')");

statement3.executeUpdate("insert into 
dbo.Company(CName,DateTimeCreated,DateTimeLastModified) 
values('"+EMpname[i]+"' ,'"+ts+"','"+ts+"')");
tx.commit();
```

This ensures that either all statements are successfully executed or none of them (rollback).
I would also consider using parametrized queries to avoid SQL injections: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java#Prepared_Statements